# How to simulate left mouse click on low level so that Microsoft virtual keyboard accept it?

Tags: c#, c++, driver

I have the task of automating some forms fill in web browser java application.

But Java have protection from such automation. It has protection from filling data using AutoIt. Because of this protection sometimes data is not filling correctly in Java form and automation process is therefore impossible.

Then I tried to use Microsoft virtual keyboard and it works good with Java forms. However it also have protection against AutoIt and when I try to generate mouse clicks on virtual keyboard using AutoIt this doesn't work. Keys are simply not pressed.

Therefore I am looking to somehow write little exe file that will just generate single mouse click, but on hardware level. This file should always run in background and do not steel focus from active window. This will allow me to use virtual keyboard to fill java forms.

I have found http://glovepie.org/ but I can not find the way to pro grammatically call left mouse click. I only can remap some keyboard key to mouse click with GlovePIE.

Also I read about keydown and keyrelease events in C++ But I am afraid that Virtual keyboard might have protection against it. Also I do not know how to write proper C++ code to generate mouse click using keydown and keyrelease.

**EDIT**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Winuser.h>

int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
    int       cmdShow)
{
    void click(){
        INPUT input = { 0 }; //INPUT structure
        // left down
        input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN; //left mouse button down
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT)); //call SendInput, pass in input to click

        Sleep(1);

        // left up
        ZeroMemory(&input, sizeof(INPUT)); //clear out input
        input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP; //left mouse button up
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT)); //call SendInput, pass in input to unclick
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious since you've mentioned autoit and java together.  Have you tried [IUIAutomation](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153520-iuiautomation-ms-framework-automate-chrome-ff-ie/)?

Answer (score 1):

```
void click(){
    INPUT input={0}; //INPUT structure
    // left down
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE; 
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN; //left mouse button down
    SendInput(1,&input,sizeof(INPUT)); //call SendInput, pass in input to click

    Sleep(1);

    // left up
    ZeroMemory(&input,sizeof(INPUT)); //clear out input
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE; 
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP; //left mouse button up
    SendInput(1,&input,sizeof(INPUT)); //call SendInput, pass in input to unclick
}
```

This is C++ Windows API code that clicks and releases the left mouse button. It's the lowest level you probably want to deal with. 
The MSDN documentation on SendInput might also be of use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: asqapro, thank you for answer. I really appreciate your help. But can you review my code that I posted in EDIT section of the question? This is my first C++ program and it's very hard to correctly do it. At the moment the build fails with errors: 'WinMain' : function cannot be overloaded,  local function definitions are illegal, IntelliSense: expected a ';'

Comment: If someone could write the fast answer what's wrong with the code that I wrote I would really appreciate it. Today is Saturday and we were planning to make Maintenance today, because it's very convenient for us.

Comment: What IDE/ compiler are you using?

    int main(){}

should work.